# WPF - Using Control Template just on one element

Tags: wpf, grid, controltemplate

My first steps in WPF and C# and i don't get it to work... :(

I have an application with two grids inside one window. I have to change the style of the first grid, so i started reading and reached using ControlTemplate. 
My Grid now looks as i wanted it. But i only want that the first grid looks this way. the second one on the same page should have another style.

Is it possible to bind the controltemplate only on one grid. Maybe by name or soemthing identifying?

My ControlTemplate Code for now i have written in window.resources looks:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                            Background="Black"
                            BorderBrush="Black" 
                            BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" 
                            CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="0,0,0,20"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF454E54" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"   Value="#FF0A3651" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF454E54" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the `Style` or `ControlTemplate` an `x:Key` ( `<Style x:Key="key" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">` ) and apply it to the element you want by setting the element's `Style` or `Template` property like this:

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource key}">
```

A `Style` without an `x:Key` is implicit and will be applied to all elements whose type matches the specified `TargetType` of the `Style`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your template under Window.Resources do it under your Grid.Resources

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Didn't know that this will work too. If i ever have to use it again i will watch out if it is better to write the template under the appropriate element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. All this is doing is setting the style of the TabItem directly.

```html
<TabItem> <!-- This is your TabItem control -->
    <TabItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <!-- ControlTemplate here -->
                    </Controltemplate
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabItem.Style>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: I tried this. But to get the selected trigger work i had to implement a control template.

Comment: Yes - you should nest your entire `<Style>` INCLUDING your `ControlTemplate` inside `<TabItem.Style>`. I've edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks again. I will test this.